# Type exists in two assemblies

Tags: asp.net, dynamic-data

I've got a web project. It was a asp .net dynamic data preview that I'm trying to bring into the version 1 dynamic data suite. 
I've crossed a lot of hurdles but now when i build i see this error:

> The type
>   'System.Web.DynamicData.FilterUserControlBase'
>   exists in both
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.6.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'
>   and
>   'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'

When I googled, the most I got was "clean the solution" (a la http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3091f8d5-4c3c-487c-88d2-da45cc15c250) but that won't work for me.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so it was a bunch of jiggerypokery on my side of things.

I had this dynamic data site, done with the preview version.  I decided to bring it into the version of of ASP .Net dynamic data.  Everything was good, deleted the old classes, added the new linq to SQL stuff, and so on.  Set up scaffolding. Then built.
Problems galore. From old type-names in my controls to duplicate assemblies being referenced.

Even though I had de-referenced the old System.Web.Extensions 3.6 library, I had neglected to modify the tag prefix setup further down in my web.config.

That proved to be key, so I had to remove improper references throughout the web.config and everything was everything.

Thanks gang.