# MVC3 Type exists in two different assemblies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm getting an error when I run my MVC3 application.

> i:\Dev\mvc3Project\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\SelectListEnum.cshtml(13): error CS0433: The type 'mvc3Project.UI.HtmlExtensions.HtmlAssist' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\fcb9f71c\d519c72a\assembly\dl3\b333487e\ed66abf6_51decb01\mvc3Project.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\fcb9f71c\d519c72a\App_Code.tfh8pvp4.dll'

I have tried deleting all the files in Temporary ASP.NET files.

The following two threads haven't helped
[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953188/type-exists-in-two-assemblies)
[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219503/asp-net-mvc-unit-tests-error-the-type-x-exists-in-both-y-and-y)

Here is my web.config. It's actually the default one VS creates for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices"
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>

        <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />

        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>

        <!--<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" localOnly="true" traceMode="SortByCategory" />-->

        <machineKey decryption="AES" 
                    validation="HMACSHA512" 
                    validationKey="AutoGenerate" 
                    decryptionKey="ABAA84D7EC4BB56D75D217CECFFB9628809BDB8BF91CFCD64568A145BE59719F" />


        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
        </authentication>

        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
                     enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
                     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                     applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </membership>

        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </profile>

        <roleManager enabled="false">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
                <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
            </providers>
        </roleManager>

        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>

    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I don't have a copy of System.Web.Mvc in the bin folder either.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is mvc3Project.UI.HtmlExtensions.HtmlAssist defined in terms of code?

Comment: App_Code?  I haven't used MVC3, but I didn't know you could have an App_Code folder/DLL in an MVC project.  One of the files that has the conflict is an App_Code.dll.

Comment: It's defined within the web application project. More specifically AppCode\HtmlExtensions.cs. It's a public static class with a bunch of static methods.

Comment: Thanks David. You saved my head from going bald. I renamed the App_Code folder to AppCode and it's working now.

Comment: Now how do I close this question? :-)

Comment: @Sir - I added an answer.  You could accept that.  Glad I could help.  And as a member of the balding society, I will try to do everything to help prevent you from joining our group.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conflict is in a folder named App_Code, which generates it's own DLL.  Sounds like you have duplicate code in that folder with something referenced somewhere else.  You could either remove that duplicate code and use the referenced assembly, or (if you need the code) rename the folder (like you stated in your comment).

I'd recommend you either remove the code or look to rename the duplicate code as it could cause confusion down the road.

Hope this helps!

Comment: MVC3 Doesn't have an app_code folder. That was for web forms.

Comment: @user441058 in the comments of the OP I ask about the stack trace and the existence of a DLL named AppCodeXXX.  In the comments you'll see that the OP has a folder named App_Code, which is a reserved folder name in web forms...kind of a leftover from web forms.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're talking about. My bad.

Comment: @user441058 No problem - that was my first reaction, too. :)

Comment: I also had the same issue and it seems that all the people I've seen who have the same problem in ASP.NET MVC, are all trying to use a folder called "App_Code". This was a reserved folder in WebForms, however it appears that some underlying "Web" dll is still referencing this. The SOLUTION is to not use that folder name, I renamed mine to Web_Helpers and viola it fixed my issues.

Answer (score 5):

If this is not working

Remove all **bin folders and obj folders**  in your solution. And also remove the files in

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\ path

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem in the web.config:

FROM:

`<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

TO:

`<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />`

Answer (score 0):

Ref: This fixed the issue and more likely to be the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21791689/1594274